# Run Application from C# in a different context

Tags: c#, .net-4.6.2

I want to build a Mater-Slave structure with console applications.

In the root directory I have my main application. After the application started it starts the slaves which are located in a subdirectory of the root directory.

Not a problem so far. The real problem is that all applications are started like they are located in root directory. So I get all files that the slave application in the root directory and no files in the slave directory.

Is it somehow possible to start the application (preferrably using the Process class or similar ones) like you would do in windows explorer with double click?

Comment: It really shouldn't matter where you start the process *from* if the application is coded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`WorkingDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of `ProcessStartInfo` to set the base directory.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("SomeApplication.exe");
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\SomeOtherDirectory";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```